# How to find out why some files won't upload?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, html, file-upload

Using the code below, I can successfully upload an xlsx file without any issues, but when I try to upload a csv version of the same file it never hits the controller. So I tried other csv files and some of them work fine and others don't hit the controller.

No errors are raised so I don't really know what to do to troubleshoot this further. I'm not even sure how to isolate whether the issue is happening after asp.net gets the request but before it hits the controller, or whether it's before it even gets posted. Any suggestions on what I can look into next?

Html:

```
<div>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="uploadFile" />
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#uploadFile').on('change', function (e) {
    var files = e.target.files;
    if (files.length > 0) {
        if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
            var data = new FormData();

            for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x++)
                data.append("file" + x, files[x]);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Home/UploadFile',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: data,
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result)
                        alert('File uploaded.');
                    else
                        alert('Error uploading file :(');
            },
                error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
                    var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3 + " " + p4;
                    if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                        err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).Message;
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("This browser doesn't support HTML5 file uploads :(");
        }
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UploadFile()
{
    try
    {
        if(Request.Files.Count == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("No file to upload!");

        var fileContent = Request.Files[0];

        if(fileContent != null && fileContent.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            Session["ImportFileId"] = ImportFiles.Save(fileContent.InputStream);
            return Json(true);
        }
        else
            return Json(false);
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return Json(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you know if no errors are given back? (you throw away `err` in your error handler without showing it)

Comment: @dandavis Dangit you're right. I thought I had an alert there. Turns out I'm exceeding the max length. Thanks!